# Symfony3 updates a bit to much

Tags: doctrine, entity, symfony

I have a CMS hobby project where I'm having problems when running an update in Symfony.

I have three Entities that link to each other.

Article Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \StaticBundle\Entity\Revision
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StaticBundle\Entity\Revision")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="revision", referencedColumnName="rid")
 * })
 */
private $revision;
```

Revision Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \StaticBundle\Entity\Content
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StaticBundle\Entity\Content")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="content", referencedColumnName="cid")
 * })
 */
private $content;
```

Content Entity:

This is a plain and simple Entity. No relations here.

Controller method:

```
/**
 * @param Entity $entity $form->getData(); (Can be Article, Page etc)
 * @param Person $person The user (FOSUserBundle)
 */

private function newRevision($entity, $person) {

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  // Either fetch Content Entity from DB or the $entity.
  $content = $em->getRepository('StaticBundle:Content')
    ->find($entity->getRevision()->getContent()->getCid());

  // Creating the new Revision Entity.
  $revision = new Revision();
  ...
  $revision->setContent($content);

  // instantiating the node type. EX: Article
  $contentType = $entity->getRevision()->getContent()->getContenttype();
  $contentTypeObject = $contentType->getNamespace() . "\\" . $contentType->getName();
  $newEntity = new $contentTypeObject();
  $newEntity->setRevision($revision);

  // Setting the value from the article form $entity to the new Entity
  $object = new \ReflectionObject($newEntity);
  foreach ($object->getMethods() as $method) {
    if($method->name != "setRevision") {
      if(substr($method->name, 0, 3) == "set") {
        $set = (string)$method->name;
        $get = "get" . substr($method->name, 3);
        $newEntity->$set($entity->$get());
      }
    }
  }

  $em->flush();
  dump($newEntity);
}
```

---

The system is suppose to be able to have multiple revisions of the "node".

EX:
Content id: 21 can have
  Revision id: 22 (name: b)
  Revision id: 23 (name: c)

But when I want to create a new Revision (id: 24 name: d), both the new and the existing Revision is updated with the new name.

So now it looks like this:

Content id: 21 can have

Revision id: 22 (name: b)

Revision id: 23 (name: d)

Revision id: 24 (name: d)

How do I avoid this? The doctrine is done with a simple flush();

Comment: Can you share your controller code for creating new entity Revision?

Comment: I've tested at bit more - and it seems like it's only the two last Revisions that are changed. So it seems like Symfony updates the active revision while inserting new revision?